# Is there a way to multithread or batch REST API calls in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, get

I've got a very long list of keys, and I am calling a REST API with each key to GET some metadata about it.

The API can only accept one key at a time, but I wondered if there was a way I could batch or multi-thread the calls from my side?

Comment: Yes, it is easy to make requests in multiple threads. The tricky part is doing so in a way which doesn't trigger rate limiting, if employed.

Comment: If you assume there's no rate limiting, what libraries / methods would I use to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other reply to this looks like ChatGPT so it should be ignored.

I did, however, use its code as a base to write a function that does what I want.

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.example.com/metadata'

def get_metadata_for_key(key):
    url = f"{API_ENDPOINT}/{key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return None

def get_save_metadata(keys, workers):
    results = {}
    batches = [keys[i : i + workers] for i in range(0, len(keys), workers)]

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        for batch in tqdm(batches):     #tqdm shows a progress bar
            futures = {key: executor.submit(get_metadata_for_key, key) for key in batch}
            futures_clean = {k: v.result() for k, v in futures.items() if v is not None}
            results.update({k: xmltodict.parse(v) for k, v in futures_clean.items()})
    
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to multithread or batch REST API calls in Python to improve the performance of your program. One way to do this is by using the `concurrent.futures` module which provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing functions using threads or processes.

Here's an example code that shows how you can use `concurrent.futures` to perform multithreaded REST API calls in batches:

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import islice

API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.example.com/metadata'

def get_metadata(keys):
    results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for batch in iter(lambda: list(islice(keys, 5)), []):
            futures = [executor.submit(get_metadata_for_key, key) for key in batch]
            results += [future.result() for future in futures]
    return results
            
def get_metadata_for_key(key):
    url = f"{API_ENDPOINT}/{key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return None
```

In this example, `get_metadata` function takes a list of keys and uses the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to `execute get_metadata_for_key` function for each key in batches of 5. The `islice` function is used to create an iterator that returns batches of 5 keys from the input list. The `executor.submit` function is used to submit a new task to the thread pool for each key in the batch, which returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` object. The `future.result()` function is used to retrieve the result of each task and append it to the results list.

You can modify the `max_workers` parameter to control the number of threads used for executing tasks. In this example, I'm using 5 threads.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tested this with a list of five keys, and it kept iterating over those five. I'd like to populate a dictionary with {key : response.content}. I'd also like it to stop when it finishes the list! How can I do those things?

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Bro its no chatgpt xd